# How to use select inside another select (Sub-Query) in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, select, nested, subquery

I need to use select id inside another select but I don't know how can do it? My idea is something like this:

```
$query10 = "SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate >= '{$from_date}' AND satellite_derived_time >= CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED)";

$query20 = "SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate >= '{$to_date}' AND satellite_derived_time >= CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED)";


$query = "SELECT * FROM $database_table WHERE id BETWEEN '$query10' AND '$query20'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JOINs

```
SELECT t.*
FROM $database_table AS tfrom
JOIN $database_table AS tto
JOIN $database_table AS t ON t.id BETWEEN tfrom.id AND tto.id
WHERE tfrom.UTCdate >= '$from_date' AND tfrom.satellite_derived_time >= CAST('$from_time' AS UNSIGNED)
AND tto.UTCdate >= '$to_date' AND tto.satellite_derived_time >= CAST('$to_time' AS unsigned)
```

or use subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM $database_table
WHERE id BETWEEN (SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate >= '{$from_date}' AND satellite_derived_time >= CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED))
             AND (SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate >= '{$to_date}' AND satellite_derived_time >= CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: Query failedsubquery returns more than one row.

Comment: I think there is a problem and it shows me above message. I used second method (subqueries).

Comment: Your original code implies that there can only be one value in `$query10` and `$query20`. How are multiple IDs supposed to be handled? Your original code doesn't make sense if there can be multiple IDs.

Comment: Yes, there can be just one value in $query10 and $query20

Comment: The error message says that they're returning more than one value.

Comment: Maybe you need `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` to select a specific row that meets the criteria.

Comment: Or `SELECT MAX(id)` or `SELECT MIN(id)`.